# Zend Server CE - ZF : cant connect to remote Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, database-connection, zend-server

Strange problem:

Running newest Version of Zend Server CE. Local installation of Oracle XE and SQLDeveloper. Connecting from SQLDeveloper to Remote/Local DB works perfect.

Connecting from Zend Server CE with PHP/Zend Framework to local Oracle XE works perfect. But connecting with the Server to an remote oracle db, gives me an error like "host not found". The "tnsnames.ora" must be correct, because SQLDeveloper is working fine with this entries..

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong system variable in path to tnsnames.ora..